# Can a Warlock take Hexblade powers/feats/etc?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, character-advancement, warlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Dungeons and Dragons 4e character take D&D Essentials class powers?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/can-a-dungeons-and-dragons-4e-character-take-dd-essentials-class-powers)

When a Warlock levels up, can they diversify into Hexblade Powers (etc) or does this require multi-classing?

Answer (score 5):

From the [previews](http://wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20101029) that I've [seen](http://wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dragon/393/393_Hexblade_Star_Pact.pdf), they are available for any warlock.

The key is that the powers are listed as "Warlock Level X"  (Where X is the respective level).  As long as you are a warlock, and are switching out a power of the appropriate level, it is allowed.

I'm not so sure about the paragon path in the Dragon Magazine article.  It has no prerequisites listed, but I'd like to have the actual text of the Heroes of Forgotten Realms book in front of me so that I could see if there is anything specific about Hexblades in there that hasn't been revealed yet.

Comment: Really this goes for all the classes/builds presented in essentials products. A power listed as "[Class] [Type] Level X" is just that, and if your character gets a power for that class at that level, and type at that level, then you can take it.

Comment: @Simon - yes, definitely!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: any power with a class name, type (at will, encounter, daily, utility) and level may be taken by a member of that class at that level if they gain that type of power.

The more complex answer, however, is a question of design philosophy.

Hexblades have:

- Eldritch Bolt
- A pact *reward*
- A pact *boon*
- A pact *weapon*

Warlocs have

- Eldritch Blast
- Eldritch Pact

  - Pact boon (hey look, the first similiarly named thing. Of course, the pact boon in warlock triggers when someone's dropped, and the pact boon in hexblade is a free power.)
- Prime Shot
- Shadow Walk
- Warlock's Curse

Therefore, the only commonalities will be feats that are either generalized to warlock or feats that modify pact boon.

Out of 110 warlock feats, the following can be shared between hexblades and warlocks:

- [Cruel whimsy](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2079)
- [Spirit Poison](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2083)
- [Yorgrix's Brutality](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2085)
- [Allegiance to the Daughter](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2191) (maybe)
- [Devil's Favor](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2194)
- [Glasya's Rebuke](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2195)
- Hellbound heart
- infernal soul
- Sacrifice to Caiphon
- Shadow's eclipse
- starfire womb
- Prisoner's resolve
- Bael Turath Born
- Warlock Implement Expertise

Of these, the only one of interest is the epic Warlock implement expertise. Functionally, there will be little feat sharing due to the complete differences in class features.

Warlocks and Hexblades can and will share utility powers. And they may share some dailies (level 5 is the only one on the preview that suggests sharing). The dailies are sharply limited due to the charisma focus of hexblade.

Therefore, while warlocks will be able to take utilities and dailies from the "other side" the V shaped stats of warlock (con or Cha as primary) and the completely different class features make most sharing superficial at best. This trend, unfortunately, seems to be strongly pronounced in *this* essentials book.

Despite the superficial similarities between the two classes, the only real link they share is in their utility powers. Don't expect the warlock feats in the essentials book to be useful to older warlocks.