# Can a Dungeons and Dragons 4e character take D&D Essentials class powers?

Tags: powers, dnd-4e

Either by retraining or gaining a level, can a old-school D&D 4e character take the daily, encounter, utility, or at-will powers listed in the [Essentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editions_of_Dungeons_&_Dragons#Dungeons_.26_Dragons_Essentials) materials?

For example, the Essentials' Fighter has two at-will stances, can a 4e character ever get that power?

Bonus Question:  Can an Essentials character take a non-Essentials power?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any class power can be taken by a character if:

- That character can take powers of that class
- The class power in question **has an explicit level** and the character is eligible to take powers of that level.  (Either from a newly gained power, or from retraining)
- The class power is of the same type (attack or utility)

This goes for Essentials characters taking regular powers and vice-versa.

The **Slayer** (I'm assuming this is what you meant by "Essentials Fighter" gains, at level 1 two stances (out of 6 to chose from).  These are all listed as `Fighter Utility` powers, so they are **not** eligible for a regular fighter to take.  Compare to the powers gained at second level which are listed at `Fighter Utility 2`.  Those are eligible for any fighter to take.

The rules for this are on p57 of the *Heroes of the Fallen Lands* book.